# Google Map JS API v3 Marker not clickable

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps-api-3

i am having a bit of a fight with the Google Map API v3 and the iPhone. I am binding a click event on the markers, but when the user-agent is iPhone, nothing is clickable (works fine on Android, Desktop browsers).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                                        alert("click")
                    }
                })(marker, i));
```

It seems Google is preventing the click event to happen when the user agent is iPhone. I've been fighting with this for 3days now, and i am really getting upset as there is no error and almost no documentation for this on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually quite simple, but not clear to debug, Google Map js API as a limit of 8 Markers you can place on a map, going above the limit apparently causes issues with the map itself.

Adding a hardcoded limit of 8 markers solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it would work everywhere if you simplified to this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(marker, i) {
                                    alert("click")
            });
```

Comment: Did so, the original was taken right from Google documentation. It did not solve the issue though.